# Can't run homestead in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel-4

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

I did everything on [Laravel homestead document](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead), when I type `homestead up`, it come out

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:763:in `chmod': Operation not permitted - /home/chan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key (Errno::EPERM)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:763:in `chmod'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:763:in `copy_insecure_private_key'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:171:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:165:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:165:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You haven't got permissions to change the permissions on /home/chan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key

Comment: Can't, if I use `sudo homestead up`, it shows `sudo: homestead: command not found`

Comment: What are the permissions for the `/home/chan/.vagrant.d` directory?

Comment: Owner is me, and mod is 777